# Problema ao salvar imagem da camera no servidor

Tags: android

Fala pessoal, estou com um problema ao salvar uma imagem da câmera no servidor. Coloquei uma imagem padrão no meu Image View e essa imagem é clicável, acionando a câmera do android. Quando a foto é tirada, ela vai pro Image View tudo certinho, porém, quando mando salvar ela a imagem que é salva é a imagem padrão que estava antes no Image View.

Classe Java:

```
public class FormProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spTypeProduct;
private EditText inputNameProduct, inputPriceProduct;
private String strPrice, compareValue, productName, productType, localFile, strBakeryId, strImage;
private Double productPrice;
private Resources resources;
private Button btnAddProduct;
public static final String APP_NAME = "PanApp";
private static final String TAG = FormProductActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String URL = "https://panapp-backend.appspot.com/_ah/api";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Long bakeryId;
private Product product;
private ImageView imageProduct;
private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
private static final int MAKE_PHOTO = 1888;
//private ImageHelper imageHelper;
private byte[] image;
private Bundle params;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent it = getIntent();
    params = it.getExtras();
    if (params != null) {
        bakeryId = params.getLong("bakeryId");
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_product);
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            callClearErrors(s);
        }
    };
    resources = getResources();
    imageProduct = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_product);
    imageProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*localFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(localFile);
            Uri localPhoto =  Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent goCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            goCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, localPhoto);

            startActivityForResult(goCamera, MAKE_PHOTO);*/

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, MAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    });

    inputNameProduct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_product_name);
    inputNameProduct.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    inputPriceProduct = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_product_price);
    spTypeProduct = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_product_type);
    btnAddProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save_product);
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Pães");
    categories.add("Bolos");
    categories.add("Cucas");
    categories.add("Bebidas");
    categories.add("Salgados");
    categories.add("Doces");
    categories.add("Frios");
    categories.add("Biscoitos");
    categories.add("Outros");
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, categories);
    spTypeProduct.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spTypeProduct.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            productType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    btnAddProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validateFields()) {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FormProductActivity.this, "Salvando produto...", "Aguarde um momento", true, false);

                new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                        String content = params[0];

                        ProductApi.Builder productBuilder = new ProductApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null).setRootUrl(URL);

                        productBuilder.setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
                        ProductApi productService = productBuilder.build();
                        product = new Product();

                        product.setProductName(productName);
                        product.setProductPrice(productPrice);
                        product.setType(productType);
                        product.setBakeryId(bakeryId);
                        //image = convertImageToByte(imageProduct);
                        //strImage = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
                        strPrice = productPrice.toString();
                        strBakeryId = bakeryId.toString();
                        product.setProductImage(strImage);

                        try {
                            productService.insert(product).execute();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                        if (result) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(FormProductActivity.this, "Produto cadastrado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(FormProductActivity.this, "Erro ao enviar registro" + strImage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }.execute(productName, strPrice, productType, strBakeryId, strImage);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void callClearErrors(Editable s) {
    if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
        clearErrorFields(inputNameProduct);
    }
}

private void clearErrorFields(EditText... editTexts) {
    for (EditText editText : editTexts) {
        editText.setError(null);
    }
}

private boolean validateFields() {
    productName = inputNameProduct.getText().toString().trim();
    productPrice = Double.valueOf(inputPriceProduct.getText().toString().trim());
    return (!isEmptyFields(productName, productPrice));
}

private boolean isEmptyFields(String name, Double price) {
    String priceAux = price.toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        inputNameProduct.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo name
        inputNameProduct.setError(resources.getString(R.string.register_name_required));
        return true;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(priceAux)) {
        inputPriceProduct.requestFocus(); //seta o foco para o campo email
        inputPriceProduct.setError(resources.getString(R.string.price_product_required));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void loadPhoto(String localPhoto) {
    Bitmap imagePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localPhoto);

    //Gerar imagem reduzida
    Bitmap reducedImagePhoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imagePhoto, 150, 200, true);

    product.setProductImage(localPhoto);

    imageProduct.setImageBitmap(reducedImagePhoto);
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    inputNameProduct.setText(product.getProductName());
    inputPriceProduct.setText(product.getProductPrice().toString());
    compareValue = product.getType();
    if (!compareValue.equals(null)) {
        int spinnerPostion = dataAdapter.getPosition(compareValue);
        spTypeProduct.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
        spinnerPostion = 0;
    }
    this.product = product;
    if (product.getProductImage() != null) {
        loadPhoto(product.getProductImage());
    }
}

public ImageView getPhoto() {
    return imageProduct;
}

public byte[] convertImageToByte(ImageView imageProduct) {

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageProduct.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    image = stream.toByteArray();

    return image;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        imageProduct = null;
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageProduct.setImageBitmap(photo);

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            image = stream.toByteArray();
            strImage = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {//Cancelou a foto
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else { //Saiu da Intent
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saiu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

Arquivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_product"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="150sp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_product"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/et_product_name"
    android:hint="Nome do produto"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_below="@id/et_product_name"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="R$: "
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_product_price"
        android:hint="Preço do produto"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Categoria"
    android:id="@+id/tv_categories"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/sp_product_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_categories">

</Spinner>

<Button
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:text="Gravar"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/btn_save_product"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sp_product_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3498db"/>
```

Se puderem ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: rpz, vc ja tentou printar esse strImage, la no onActivityResult e antes de salvar pra ver se são a mesma coisa?

Comment: Sim, coloquei um print e dava o mesmo binário sempre. Dai desinstalei e instalei de novo o apk e deu certo. Agora outra dúvida, preciso salvar a foto na memória do celular? Tem como fazer sem guardar essa imagem?